# Change string to integer in python / pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to change a string to a float value in a dataframe.

```
#showing dataframe for illustration`

IN: df2[:5]

OUT:     TRD_EXCTN_DT   ASCII_RPTD_VOL_TX
    0    08/13/2010      1000000
    1    08/16/2010      1MM+
    2    08/16/2010      369000
    3    08/16/2010      1MM+
    4    08/16/2010      1MM+
```

output concatenates the string even though I thought I had changed it to a float. I need to operate on the number so a string does not work.

```
IN: df2.loc[df2['ASCII_RPTD_VOL_TX'] == '1MM+', 'ASCII_RPTD_VOL_TX'] = 1000005
df2.ASCII_RPTD_VOL_TX.astype(float)
df2['b'] = df2['ASCII_RPTD_VOL_TX'] + df2['ASCII_RPTD_VOL_TX']
df2[:3]

OUT:        TRD_EXCTN_DT   ASCII_RPTD_VOL_TX       b
    0        08/13/2010      1000000         10000001000000
    1        08/16/2010      1000005         2000010
    2        08/16/2010      369000          369000369000`
```

also,

```
In[22]:df2.dtypes

Out[22]:TRD_EXCTN_DT         object
ASCII_RPTD_VOL_TX    object
b                    object
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to change your second line to `df2['ASCII_RPTD_VOL_TX']=df2.ASCII_RPTD_VOL_TX.astype(float)`.

The reason you are getting strange result is that your 1st and 3rd row, ASCII_RPTD_VOL_TX column cells are still in `str`. `+` is doing string `concatenate` there for those cells.

Comment: Wow, first StackOverflow question was awesome. You have a very appreciative rookie programmer. Thank you my friend.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Also please check the answer as accepted as answer, so other user knows that you have already got a working solution and won't spend time reinvent another solution. And I will make some edit to make your code block looks better.

Comment: Great, checked it. How do you get the code block to not indent on the first line. seems thats my issue. Again, appreciate the help.